# Items of nested Linear Layout not clicked

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an MvxListView which contains items which are based on `MvxLinearLayouts`. The goal is to get a grouped list. This works so far.

[image]

The issue I have, is that the click event is now catched by the linear Layout and not the item I click on. I tried to make the ListView and the LinearLayout above not clickable but that didn't work.
Here is my code:

MvxListView:

```
    <MvxListView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/payment_List"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_payment_grouped"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Source" />
```

listitem_payment_grouped:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        local:MvxBind="Text Key" />
    <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/payment_List"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_payment"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource .;ItemClick EditCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

listitem_payment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"            
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:translationZ="3dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            local:MvxBind="Text Date, Converter=DateTimeFormat" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            local:MvxBind="Text PaymentAmount(., ChargedAccount)" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            local:MvxBind="Text Category.Name" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            local:MvxBind="Visible IsCleared" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_recurring"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            local:MvxBind="Visible IsRecurring" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your java code. I guess you have set onClickListner of LinearLayout..!!

Comment: It's an xamarin app with mvvmcross therefore there is no java code and the click should be bound. But you brought up a good point. the issue seems that in the listitem_payment_grouped the data context changed therefore there is no EditCommand anymore..

Answer (score 0):

If so then you have to indicate that the views created by the `ListAdapter` contains focusable items by explicitly adding [`setItemsCanFocus(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setItemsCanFocus(boolean)) in your listView,

```
myListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Comment: I added this line to the code FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.payment_List).ItemsCanFocus = true;
but that doesn't work either. I also tried to add a             android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants". But without success aswell. I updated the code in the original post.